# How to convert a dd.MM.yyyy string to a Date object

Tags: typescript, date

I am trying to convert a date string of the format `dd.MM.yyyy` to a Date object. I have tried the following :

```
if( typeof myVar === 'string') {
      let myDate = new Date(myVar);
      if (myDate.getTime() < this.getMinDate().getTime()) /** compare two dates */
          //omitted source code 

}
```

`this.getMinDate().getTime()` reads `1612989937059` while `myDate.getTime()` reads `NaN`. I have tried other date format patterns such as `dd-MM-yyyy` and `dd/MM/yyyy`. None of them seems to work either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: `new Date(...)` requires the input to be in [a specific format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to have it in that format, you can rearrange it quick before using the date object as it expects a certain format..

Something like this could work.

```
if( typeof myVar === 'string') {
      let dateArr = myVar.split('.');

      let myDate = new Date(dateArr[1] + '-' + dateArr[0] + '-' + dateArr[2]);

      if (myDate.getTime() < this.getMinDate().getTime()) /** compare two dates */
          //omitted source code 

}
```